# What is the term for full-fledged packages like PyQt and PySide?

Tags: python, pyqt, terminology, pyside

I learned about them for GUIs, and they are indeed my favourite Python option for such purposes. However, they are so much more than that. They implement network sockets, media management, regular expressions, basic geometry, stuff like `QVariant` is basically a dynamic attribute handler...

I mean, it seems weird to just call them "GUI packages". It can be as little as a GUI, but it can also be pretty much an entire mask on top Python where you never use a naked function and rely on `QObjects` for everything.

Is there a name for this concept? Are there others that I should be aware about if I'm doing, say, scientific programming?

Comment: I'm not sure you've defined the concept precisely enough to answer, but perhaps you'd be satisfied with the word "framework"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frameworks, platforms, toolkits. PyQT calls itself a toolkit. [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX) is a full featured framework like you described, and it is intended to run on platforms like Windows and Xbox. I use the [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) framework for web development, but most of it's core functionality is either in the NodeJS server, which is not officially referred to as a framework AFAIK; it exposes pretty much the whole OS through a javascript interface for server side interweb code. For scientific programming, Matlab and Octave both just call themselves languages, but I would call them platforms because they have a graphical interface and GUI building tools, and a whole ecosystem of modules, and because your code lives inside of their system. OpenGL, scipy and numpy are libraries, by contrast, because they are used as a component inside of your project. And then there are content management systems (CMS) like [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) and [Drupal](http://drupal.org/), enterprise resource planning systems (ERP) like [Tryton](http://www.tryton.org/), and probably a bunch of other sub-categories of the "framework" and "platform" categories of software.

All in all, it's not easy to [categorize](http://xkcd.com/867/) software. We need to standardise a taxonomy, and then make [new](http://xkcd.com/927/) standardized taxonomies to make up for deficiencies in the first one ;)

Comment: I had a job interview that wanted me to do some coding, and they said not to use a "framework". One mistake I made was trying to figure out more precisely what they meant by "framework". Did they mean not to import really _big_ packages, and if so, how big? Is `import sys` ok? What about `from PySide import QtGui`? They said "Don't use Django or Rails." Not sure why they didn't just say that. My point is, the semantics aren't clear of the term "framework", but it definitely includes Django. Oh, and I didn't get that job.

Comment: @neuronet That could be a good thing; sounds like they might be suffering from NiH syndrome. Good luck with the job search! Firing blind advice: Try to get a careers.SE invite if you can and get a _very_ small but modern project going on github. Having repos on GH helped me land my last job. No one even looked at my stuff, they were just stoked that I had enough confidence to show off my code in public.